# Getting Nil value while importing csv file into rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am trying to import all csv file data to my rails db but one attributes Area value getting nil data

my csv file data
[image]

IN my Seed file

```
require 'csv'

csv_text = File.read(Rails.root.join('db/product_data1.csv'))
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1') do |row|
  Ada.create!( {
    Area: row["Area"], 
    Item: row["Item"],
    Year: row["Year"], 
    Value: row["Value"]
  } ) 
end
```

in rails console i am geeting Area data is nil.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSV.foreach Not Reading First Column in CSV File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57418707/csv-foreach-not-reading-first-column-in-csv-file)

Comment: Please replace the picture of your CSV file with text, thereby allowing readers to cut-and-paste your CSV data to test their code.

Answer (score 0):

I change the code it work for me.

```
  Area: row["Area"], 
  Item: row["Item"],
  Year: row["Year"], 
  Value: row["Value"]
```

into

```
   Area: row[0], 
   Item: row[1],
   Year: row[3], 
   Value: row[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the file is saved with the correct encoding. I tried the same data with your example code and it worked for me.

You can verify it by copying over the same data to excel / google sheets, and save as .csv.

You could also check out this answer [CSV.foreach Not Reading First Column in CSV File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57418707/csv-foreach-not-reading-first-column-in-csv-file)